# Footer appears dis-attached on some pages

Tags: css

I'm working on this website now and I've bumped into an annoying problem. On some pages the footer appears to be "dis-attached" from the body of the content, but on some pages it does not. I can't seem to figure out why, I start removing elements 1 by 1 until it fixes but it never does. Please have a look [LINK REMOVED]

I observed this bug in chrome, firefox and opera latest versions

it appears dis-attached on the Home page, and it appears attached, as should, on the FAQ page for example

Comment: Hi, please check out [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/126000#126000) thanks!

Comment: **Some pages?** What pages? **dis-attached from the body** what do you mean?

Comment: @Pekka I agree but if you take a look at any category's latest questions you'll notice that 90% of questions are localized, I'm not saying it's ok but where else could I possibly seek help?

Comment: @hRvoed Well it appears dis-attached on the Home page, and it appears attached, as should, on the FAQ page for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display:block; margin: 0px auto;` to `#paper` div.

**EDIT:** the H2 on the FAQ page is already set to `display: block;` but the `.main` div is set to `display: inline-block;` on the home page, hence the difference.

Comment: So I could just add `inline-block` display to the `.main` div as an easier fix? Is it really a big deal if I use `inline-block` elements instead of `block` ones? I'm not quite a css guru as you may have already figured `:D`

Comment: You should add block to both and avoid inline-block unless necessary, it's not a big deal, but i personally just think using inline-block usually causes troubleshooting like this later on. I think divs are block by default anyway.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, having in mind the core of the problem I wrote about in the first place. I'm switching to block elements! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because your main div's are inline-block, why? if you have width, you can use margin:0 auto; to align in center:

This solved the problem at first:

```
.dbi, .imgHolder a, .optionsList:active .optionsHolder, .datePicker span {
  display: block; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Still you need to fix this whole site to use block elements properly

Comment: uf... I was 45sec later :/

Comment: yeah, but you had a longer answer to type though :p

Comment: I never suspected that.. But how come it only makes an issue out of it on some pages? +rep to both

Comment: I think something due to line-height and inline elements. Since in FAQ you have no content at all, nothing to conflict about

Comment: Also! The there is **.oh {overflow: hidden;}**, changing to **.oh{overflow: visible;}** will do the work

Comment: @hRvoed I use the `oh` class in order to get the element, that I'm assigning it to, to expand to the available width after floating elements have took their place. It doesn't work out with visible overflow. It's quite a neat trick although it seems more like a hack to me :/